# How to use Phoenix Channels with JSON?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am looking to create a REST application. How to use Phoenix Channels with JSON responses, without javascript?

*Using automatic translator*

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use channels? For a simple RESTful API, channels are not necessary, you don't even need phoenix (Plug would be sufficient).

Comment: Hello! I want to create a more or less similar to the Uber app.

Comment: Since Phoenix channels are using websockets, I doubt it's possible to use them without JavaScript.

Comment: I understand. Maybe someone has a solution where there is javascript, but I do not need to work directly with him. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "without javascript"? How are you going to send a request to the app? Using some other language? Which one?